# Model name is being displayed in Django template

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django so I'm just building a few simple apps to increase my knowledge. I am trying to display a concatenated list, however when I display the list it shows the model names like so:

```
[<FamousQuote: Be yourself; everyone else is already taken>][<InfamousQuote: . I dunno. Either way. >]
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    famous_quote = FamousQuote.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]
    infamous_quote = InfamousQuote.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]

    compiled = [famous_quote, infamous_quote]

    return render(request, 'funnyquotes/index.html', {'compiled': compiled})
```

and my index.html file:

```
{% if compiled %}
    {{ compiled|join:"" }}
{% else %}
    <p>No quotes for you.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or a better way I could do this?

Comment: what's your desired result?

Comment: can you please post your `models.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of lists, so the unicode representation of the list contains the `<ObjectName:string>`, where if you had a list of model objects, you'd get a proper `__unicode__` representation of your objects.

Ultimately, the template is automatically trying to convert python objects into its string representations, which in the case of the `QuerySet` is `[<object: instance.__unicode__()>]`.

You have clearly already defined *your* desired string representation for object instances - you just need to make sure the template engine receives those instances - not other classes.

Look at the difference in output in a shell.

```
print(FamousQuote.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1])   # calls str(QuerySet)
# vs
print(FamousQuote.objects.order_by('?')[0]) # calls str(FamousQuote)
```

Either update your view

```
compiled = [famous_quote[0], infamous_quote[0]]
```

Or your template

```
{% for quotes in compiled %}{{ quotes|join:"" }}{% endfor %}
```

### TL;DR

You have lists of lists so you are joining the string representation of the lists, not the instances.